# Determining what RNA SEQ data is filtered on volcano plot

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, rna-seq

I am using RNA seq data to analyze genes via a volcano plot (which compares differential gene expression of bacteria with and without antibiotic) in R. After having created my plot, I am unsure why some of my values which read "0" TPM in one condition and a TPM value that's not "0" in the other condition were not determined to be differentially expressed. Some of the genes on my volcano plot have this difference in TPM and show up as significant on my plot while others with this "0" value difference are not considered to be significant according to my plot.

Here is a sample of my data
(UO1_D712_##### represents the locus number, the top column represents the different replicates where "1" is untreated and "2" is treated with antibiotic, the letters next to the numbers represent a different technical replicate):

```
structure(list(`1` = c("U01_D712_00001", 

"U01_D712_00002", "U01_D712_00003", 
"U01_D712_00004", "U01_D712_00005", "U01_D712_00006", "U01_D712_00007", 
"U01_D712_00008", "U01_D712_00009", "U01_D712_00010", "U01_D712_00011", 
"U01_D712_00012", "U01_D712_00013", "U01_D712_00014", "U01_D712_00015", 
"U01_D712_00016", "U01_D712_00017", "U01_D712_00018", "U01_D712_00019", 
"U01_D712_00020", "U01_D712_00021", "U01_D712_00022", "U01_D712_00023", 
"U01_D712_00024", "U01_D712_00025", "U01_D712_00026", "U01_D712_00027", 
"U01_D712_00028", "U01_D712_00029", "U01_D712_00030"), `1a` = c("6.590456502", 
"6.741694688", "7.110342585", "6.299482433", "2.77173982", "2.470330508", 
"3.827125186", "6.267229842", "5.524708663", "2.657913228", "2.87209859", 
"7.479820548", "4.980185572", "4.210955199", "0", "4.492492822", 
"3.611091371", "3.714270433", "7.455036914", "7.045203025", "6.061860857", 
"2.925268313", "6.544077039", "5.747318013", "9.97083444", "9.22523089", 
"4.20205383", "6.097040679", "2.621192351", "0"), `1b` = c("6.544454427", 
"6.601489488", "7.134224619", "5.814043553", "3.280958379", "2.649180803", 
"3.860542083", "6.256648363", "5.380427766", "2.581027705", "3.016132165", 
"7.405329447", "4.701503289", "4.073814818", "0", "4.304196924", 
"3.515977329", "3.843535649", "7.342972625", "6.966606769", "6.122878624", 
"3.007522306", "6.495797641", "5.965431621", "9.828050269", "9.219563915", 
"4.065778989", "6.105331066", "3.061209408", "0"), `1c` = c("6.608196006", 
"6.743010138", "7.102600793", "6.146518601", "3.555184202", "2.364971542", 
"4.034053983", "6.158523627", "5.656051812", "2.658660735", "3.054717455", 
"7.392164473", "4.950953264", "4.277770477", "0", "4.507936666", 
"3.794842979", "3.610794578", "7.471646548", "7.104792624", "6.484767016", 
"3.071205184", "6.584425715", "6.20466015", "9.986342122", "9.282943758", 
"4.179958213", "6.219551653", "2.984738345", "0"), `1d` = c("6.547155382", 
"6.558328892", "6.992501615", "6.449558793", "3.059801464", "2.418800257", 
"3.96498952", "6.013208538", "5.279919645", "2.893295085", "1.750510471", 
"7.408735671", "4.9425624", "3.804549986", "0", "4.174835979", 
"3.806006888", "3.570390524", "7.641137006", "6.976672494", "6.363030106", 
"3.083061726", "6.300910093", "6.007490342", "9.926316442", "9.09671588", 
"4.320556917", "6.153860107", "2.877230446", "0"), `1e` = c("6.626724417", 
"6.577345176", "7.156821278", "6.296873411", "3.618089702", "2.394444986", 
"4.129376392", "6.011715246", "5.31197869", "2.00754706", "2.695493528", 
"7.538910448", "4.606060035", "3.909472643", "0", "4.346616047", 
"3.468681284", "3.338231445", "7.559599613", "7.1527452", "6.232923513", 
"3.108624209", "6.535435309", "6.12922864", "10.13108497", "9.310331313", 
"3.959568571", "6.182335537", "2.902736258", "0"), `1f` = c("6.419219179", 
"6.650459302", "7.319125725", "5.570869357", "2.962845933", "2.55903176", 
"4.087597573", "5.995610538", "5.386268651", "2.750800859", "2.416572678", 
"7.579148955", "3.952633067", "3.615227674", "0", "4.562838935", 
"3.76942104", "3.920096905", "7.935320749", "7.501470652", "6.13700099", 
"3.123910608", "6.035971952", "5.706235015", "9.254751395", "8.379630979", 
"4.51391973", "5.6890651", "2.43285316", "0"), `1g` = c("6.553221221", 
"6.633949852", "7.182305386", "5.769365973", "2.721354972", "1.668390466", 
"4.148367057", "6.240883382", "5.458877133", "1.733842637", "2.723803355", 
"7.522249899", "4.149567197", "3.780763096", "0", "4.496306813", 
"3.645643535", "3.851001768", "7.678552875", "7.283411279", "6.591585956", 
"2.879345378", "6.389427003", "5.911222165", "9.851084493", "9.084575304", 
"4.272587776", "5.974762147", "2.98852705", "0"), `2a` = c("9.769887737", 
"4.550226652", "1.869021464", "4.944848987", "7.9678549", "2.682865013", 
"8.495575559", "2.234521659", "3.667196316", "9.180445037", "3.210107621", 
"7.21523691", "5.714579923", "5.423986751", "9.118981459", "8.635701597", 
"2.742889473", "3.712618983", "8.006057144", "4.999541279", "10.54351774", 
"5.880978085", "7.145433526", "6.982416661", "9.339651188", "5.360835327", 
"4.699680905", "3.423826225", "6.408271885", "5.038170992"), 
    `2b` = c("10.26397519", "1.945664005", "2.086763158", "2.800904763", 
    "8.583418657", "1.536094563", "9.32057547", "3.10685839", 
    "4.224502319", "10.1252842", "1.811175407", "5.714439316", 
    "6.039142559", "3.833361174", "9.757360286", "9.565906731", 
    "1.523640473", "2.315033488", "6.312524363", "4.889986456", 
    "10.23020108", "4.848727685", "7.533256999", "7.138160378", 
    "10.30380331", "3.955469283", "3.167940742", "3.599655687", 
    "4.828945262", "3.701043054"), `2c` = c("9.478481216", "2.789289131", 
    "3.393949527", "3.754810933", "8.710777154", "1.806170784", 
    "9.150005253", "2.612275457", "4.961073313", "9.802701699", 
    "2.933183115", "6.532384958", "6.919449225", "4.432699799", 
    "9.715063475", "9.265691356", "1.412064593", "3.330131873", 
    "6.665979896", "5.158526421", "9.417365584", "4.899531204", 
    "8.173459354", "7.271400938", "9.813068613", "4.384622077", 
    "3.700645365", "4.457874829", "5.649440022", "3.531010379"
    ), `2d` = c("8.199795497", "2.565711524", "2.202287889", 
    "3.856354444", "7.380224849", "2.192476466", "8.14446837", 
    "1.144258862", "3.31447122", "8.713146629", "2.697890381", 
    "6.304428859", "5.745291803", "4.898396114", "9.173362747", 
    "8.339933849", "3.159678152", "4.094587234", "7.608649692", 
    "5.280206424", "10.34630403", "5.098585806", "7.262400625", 
    "6.150190905", "9.316698845", "5.073027993", "4.695003229", 
    "2.485847024", "5.545300465", "4.350571411"), `2e` = c("8.74935033", 
    "3.739489484", "0.217205045", "4.413657999", "8.745525588", 
    "3.657060086", "9.279834921", "2.898951179", "4.282874018", 
    "9.610485827", "3.561102455", "7.228334332", "6.388491443", 
    "4.389908652", "8.781086564", "9.178866581", "2.374603596", 
    "3.961037408", "7.864369809", "3.654728044", "10.15284858", 
    "5.894439123", "7.68020282", "7.12243523", "9.998637438", 
    "5.092174395", "4.111530392", "3.776835632", "5.624523213", 
    "4.095011377"), `2f` = c("7.648310926", "4.345557215", "1.986576876", 
    "4.99426288", "7.087937177", "2.810917253", "7.77706637", 
    "2.62822773", "3.581811188", "8.470225989", "3.335757437", 
    "7.416094847", "5.208841128", "5.536128034", "8.255571138", 
    "7.993319997", "1.9209089", "3.573861828", "7.318814519", 
    "5.233804806", "11.05855833", "6.247720809", "6.673407583", 
    "6.029960625", "8.806867591", "5.459208493", "4.001428729", 
    "3.609936979", "5.876522973", "4.652839671"), `2g` = c("7.555235468", 
    "3.892899549", "1.726443458", "5.304546796", "7.039588042", 
    "3.027235295", "7.703852207", "1.753183519", "2.909288568", 
    "8.385169315", "3.902707541", "7.523315081", "4.978364017", 
    "5.49103181", "8.096218606", "7.944822989", "2.352609608", 
    "4.155433517", "7.227355741", "5.532668321", "11.24946953", 
    "6.159185473", "6.443203375", "5.931761874", "8.7421732", 
    "5.502000205", "4.652883503", "3.458323017", "6.566487449", 
    "4.89790353")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The design matrix:

```
structure(list(SampleID = c("1a ", "1b", "1c", 

"1d", "1e", "1f", 
"1g", "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "2f", "2g"), Group = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Replicate = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"
)), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I read through this edgeR user manual to write my code: http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf

Here is how I wrote my code to sample the RNA seq data (note ~/Documents/VOLCANO/R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug.csv refers to the the sample of data above and ~/Documents/VOLCANO/R10LB_0vs0.5_designmatrix.csv refers to the above design matrix):

```
R10LB_0vs0.5 <- read.csv2("~/Documents/VOLCANO/R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug.csv", sep=",", check.names = F)
R10LB_0vs0.5 <- janitor::remove_empty(R10LB_0vs0.5, which = "cols")
R10LB_0vs0.5_design <- read.csv2("~/Documents/VOLCANO/R10LB_0vs0.5_designmatrix.csv", sep=",")

#Set rownames
rownames(R10LB_0vs0.5) <- R10LB_0vs0.5$`1`
R10LB_0vs0.5 <- R10LB_0vs0.5[,-1]

#colnames(R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug) <- R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug[1,]
#R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug <- R10LB_0ugvs0.5ug[-1,]

#Convert to Matrix
R10LB_0vs0.5 <- data.matrix(R10LB_0vs0.5)

#Create DGEList
R10LB_0vs0.5 <- DGEList(counts = R10LB_0vs0.5, group = R10LB_0vs0.5_design$Group)
str(R10LB_0vs0.5)

#Design Matrix
Group <- as.vector(as.character(R10LB_0vs0.5_design$Group))
Replicate <- as.vector((R10LB_0vs0.5_design$Replicate))
R10LB_0vs0.5_designmatrix <- model.matrix(~0+Group+Replicate)

#Filter
keep <- filterByExpr(R10LB_0vs0.5)
R10LB_0vs0.5_filter <- R10LB_0vs0.5[keep, keep.lib.sizes = FALSE]

#Estimate Sample Dispersion
R10LB_0vs0.5_Disp <- estimateDisp(R10LB_0vs0.5_filter, R10LB_0vs0.5_designmatrix)

#Create Contrasts (Group Comparisons)
CONTRASTS <- makeContrasts( Group1vs2 = Group1-Group2,
                            levels = R10LB_0vs0.5_designmatrix)

#GLM Fit for Group 1 vs. Group 2
R10LB_0vs0.5fit <- glmFit(R10LB_0vs0.5_Disp, contrast = CONTRASTS[,1])
R10LB_0vs0.5lrt <- glmLRT(R10LB_0vs0.5fit)
R10LB_0vs0.5TT <- topTags(R10LB_0vs0.5lrt, n=nrow(R10LB_0vs0.5_Disp))
write.csv(R10LB_0vs0.5TT, file = "R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison.csv")
saveRDS(R10LB_0vs0.5TT, file = "R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison.RDS")
```

Here is my code for formatting the data into a volcano plot:

```
    #Basic scatter plot: x is "logFC", y is "PValue"
ggplot(data = R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison, aes(x = logFC, y = PValue)) + geom_point()

#Doesn't look quite like a Volcano plot... convert the p-value into a -log10(p-value)
p4 <- ggplot(data = R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison, aes(x = logFC, y = -log10(PValue))) + geom_point() + theme_minimal()

#Add vertical lines for logFC thresholds, and one horizontal line for the p-value threshold
p5 <- p4 + geom_vline(xintercept = c(-0.6, 0.6), col = "red") + geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "red")

# The significantly differentially expressed genes are the ones found in the upper-left and upper-right corners.
# Add a column to the data frame to specify if they are UP- or DOWN- regulated (log2FoldChange respectively positive or negative)

# add a column of NAs
R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$diffexpressed <- "NO"
# if logFC > 0.6 and PValue < 0.05, set as "UP" 
R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$diffexpressed[R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$logFC > 0.6 & R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$PValue < 0.05] <- "UP"
# if logFC < -0.6 and PValue < 0.05, set as "DOWN"
R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$diffexpressed[R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$logFC < -0.6 & R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$PValue < 0.05] <- "DOWN"

# Re-plot but this time color the points with "diffexpressed"
p4 <- ggplot(data=R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(PValue), col=diffexpressed)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal()

# Add lines as before...
p5 <- p4 + geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.6, 0.6), col="red") + geom_hline(yintercept=-log10(0.05), col="red")

## Change point color 

# 1. by default, it is assigned to the categories in an alphabetical order):
p6 <- p5 + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "black", "red"))

# 2. to automate a bit: create a named vector: the values are the colors to be used, the names are the categories they will be assigned to:
mycolors <- c("blue", "red", "black")
names(mycolors) <- c("DOWN", "UP", "NO")
p6 <- p5 + scale_colour_manual(values = mycolors)

# Now write down the name of genes beside the points...
# Create a new column "delabel" to de, that will contain the name of genes differentially expressed (NA in case they are not)
R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$delabel <- NA
R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$delabel[R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$diffexpressed != "NO"] <- R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$gene_symbol[R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison$diffexpressed != "NO"]

ggplot(data=R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(PValue), col=diffexpressed, label=delabel)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal() +geom_text()

# Finally, we can organize the labels nicely using the "ggrepel" package and the geom_text_repel() function
# load library
library(ggrepel)
# plot adding up all layers we have seen so far
ggplot(data=R10LB_0vs0.5_comparison, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(PValue), col=diffexpressed, label=delabel)) +geom_point() + theme_minimal() +geom_text_repel() + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "black", "red")) + geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.6, 0.6), col="red") +geom_hline(yintercept=-log10(0.05), col="red")
```

This is the volcano plot I currently have with all of my data:
[image: volcano plot]

Can you explain how some of these functions filtered my data (i.e. filterByExpr, estimateDisp, makeContrasts, glmFit, glmLRT)? Why are some of my data points that change from 0 TPM in one condition to some value in another condition showing up on my plot while others are not?

Are there other specific filtering processes you would recommend to change, fix, and/or improve my volcano plot?

Comment: DGE testing is a complex statistical problem. Often low expression genes are filtered out in a first pass simply because they are highly prone to resulting in false positives. So, they may be getting dropped as part of the `filterByExpr` step. Alternatively, high variance within a condition undermines confidence in the statistical significance of the mean difference across conditions.

Comment: @merv Is there a way I should look at the variance of my data? As in is there a threshold for variance between my replicates that causes them to be filtered out by filterByExpr or other functions? Or do you believe I should just accept that my data analysis is valid or "correct"? And do you have any suggestions for specific places to look to learn how these functions work so I can attempt to solve or observe these potential problems?

Comment: These are not simple questions and this is not the appropriate forum (voting to close). Try asking on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ For statistical foundations, I recommend [Modern Statistics for Modern Biology](https://web.stanford.edu/class/bios221/book/); for specific bioinformatic tools, read both the manual and the original publication.

Comment: @merv Thank you for the references